Page showing closed version of nav bar first
I am creating a hamburger navbar. I've got the look down but for some reason when page becomes smaller it first shows the closed version of the navbar and the user will have to click the x before being able to see screen again
I've tried creating navs around the code but it didn't fix the problem as I simply replaced by header with nav
